# brew and jhbuild error

Tags: macos, gtk, gegl, jhbuild

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7

At first, I used jhbuild to install some libs.It install libs in "/Users/dinosaur/gtk/inst/lib/" I think it not good.
so I remove   directory.

Home Brew is very good.so I want to install gegl with brew. So I input "brew install gegl" in terminal.But get a error:

```
grep: /Users/dinosaur/gtk/inst/lib/libiconv.la: No such file or directory
sed: /Users/dinosaur/gtk/inst/lib/libiconv.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/Users/dinosaur/gtk/inst/lib/libiconv.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [text.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

It seems brew look for libs at jhbuild build path. But I'v removed it.

How can I clean the jhbuild setting, Or another way to build gegl with brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo brew install libiconv
sudo brew link libiconv
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: When I do `brew install libiconv`, it prints "Error: No available formula for libiconv." When I do `brew link libiconv`, it prints "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv." What else can I try?